# Clang disable Case Sensitive header file inclusion

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, clang

In Linux when invoking clang compiler with clang++ with Command for the code,

```
main.cpp:

#include "Sample.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

```
include/sample.h

# HEADER FILE IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE
```

```
clang++ main.cpp -I"include"
```

produces error (fatal error: 'Sample.h' file not found). What i want is a case insensitive header file lookup.

But i found some links which says in linux it's by default behavior of linux [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951969/9645404). Also i found a llvm thread which says it's fixed and released [link](https://reviews.llvm.org/D21113). But, I couldn't found the relevant compiler flag for the same (-fcase-insensitive-paths).

Also, tried Solution provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54153221/9645404).

##### Clang Version : 16.0.0

##### Ubuntu Version : 20.04

*May be i think I'm missing out the exact compiler flag. Can anyone provide me a compiler level 
 solution to lookup for Include path with case insensitive lookup when invoking Clang?*

Comment: Are you forced into this situation?  Must your header files be misspelled?  Or is this more for your convenience?

Comment: That is an operating system issue, not a clang issue.  Short of running the build on Windows (perhaps cross-compiling for Linux) there is not much you can do.  In Linux Sample.h and sample.h just refer to different files.  It will be easier to either correct the code or rename the files.

Comment: What in that link suggests it is _"fixed and released"_?

Comment: that patch hasn't been applied, see "needs review" at the top of the page

Comment: I would just say to type the filenames correctly. Or fix the filenames. The request is to just bury bad code/design.

Comment: ... this is interesting however: https://www.phoronix.com/news/EXT4-Case-Insensitive-Linux-5.2.  If I understand that right, it would enable you to make the lookup case insensitive (like Windows) for just the include directory in question without modifying the code or filenames.  Still not an issue for SO though.

Comment: That's why one of the unbreakable rules in our coding standard is all filenames will be lowercase, ascii characters only, and no spaces.

Comment: @DrewDormann Not misspelled here. I'm trying a static analysis in linux (Avoiding compilation).

Comment: @Clifford and @ sweenish I can't modify source neither the lookup files. The size is massive in lines.

Comment: We faced a similar problem while porting a very large windows application to linux, and ultimately put in the work to make filenames and includes consistent. However, until we did, we used WSL1 and the code was on an NTFS drive. That way the files were case insensitive. Also, there seems to be a way to mount NTFS drives case insensitive in Linux directly: https://serverfault.com/q/901855

Comment: Also, the last time I checked a few months ago, telling clang directly to ignore case was simply broken.

Comment: "_The size is massive in lines_" - and global regex search and replace tools are legion. Number of lines is no barrier to that solution.  However that is entirely your constraint, it does not invalidate the solution just because you choose not to apply it.